# next.js - getInitialProps does not work in component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here's my code

```
import React from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import Book from './Book'

function getNum(val) {
    val = +val || 0;
    return val;
}

class BookList extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {;
        const res = await fetch('/api/books');
        const json = await res.json();
        return { books: json }
    }

    render() {
        var books = this.props.books;
```

For some reason "books" in the render function is undefined. Why doesn't getInitialProps work in a component?

Comment: Doesn't fetch require the full URL?

Comment: It seems `res` is `undefined`

Comment: Is this a "page" component?

Comment: the code looks fine. Did you console.log res and json? Maybe there's something wrong with the response itself... give it a try with some test API like https://swapi.co/

Answer (score 4):

`getInitialProps` can only be added to the default component exported by a page, adding it to any other component won't work.

Answer (score 3):

`getInitialProps` works only at pages level, not at components level.

```
sgetInitialProps can not be used in children components, only in the default export of every page
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#caveats